# MVC 5 - Precompiling views only works from the command prompt

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, msbuild, windows-10

I have a strange issue that hopefully, someone can help me with. I got a new laptop and I'm trying to publish the same ASP.NET MVC 5 project on the new machine with precompiled views. However, when I do a publish with "*Precompile during publishing*" option checked, it does not create the precompiled views. Now, if I copy the exact command that it ran and run it in the Command Prompt, the precompiled views are created.

Here are the details. Both machines have Windows 10 Anniversary Update (Version 1607) with Visual Studio 2013 Update 5. Publishing the app on the old machine with the same publish profile generates the precompiled views. On the new machine, publishing from the "*Publish Web*" dialog runs without errors, but no precompiled views are generated. I then copied this exact command to the Command Prompt that VS used to precompile:

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p C:\MyApp\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source -c C:\MyApp\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir
```

When I ran it, it created the precompiled views in the `TempBuildDir\bin` directory!

The only difference I can think of between the machines is the Windows Updates.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You have an option on your publish settings to precompile the application. When Folder Publish is selected , Publish -> Settings -> File Publish Options -> Select Precompile During Publishing.

Comment: @txfun I have set that. Again, it works on one machine and not the other. Same settings.

Comment: are you saving and pushing the publish settings into your repo?

Comment: @txfun yes I am. thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into exactly the same problem.

It could be an issue with compressed folders (the drive is not compressed, but individual folders are). For some reason, the .compiled files are simply not generated.

This still applies to VS2019 and MVC5. (The latest toolchain as of today. Probably a .NET Framework issue, unrelated to VS and MsBuild versions).

This thread helped me find the solution (see the last answer):
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb6a4239-9765-4021-a7ab-e5ad3d8aef06/missing-compiled-files-when-publishing-an-aspnet-mvc-4-project-to-filesystem-on-tfs-build-server?forum=msbuild

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the x64 verson of Windows?

Also you can try set $(AspnetCompilerPath) manually:

```
msbuild.exe /p:AspnetCompilerPath="C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe"
```

or add it to your project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AspnetCompilerPath Condition=" '$(AspnetCompilerPath)'=='' " >C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe</AspnetCompilerPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I've made this assumption, because the `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets` file contains the string:

```
 We can't use the in-place aspnet_compiler because it will output to the aspnet temp folder which is only suiteable to run on the current machine.
```

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 64-bit, but compiling a 32-bit mixed mode MVC 5 app. Unfortunately, adding the `AspnetCompilerPath` property did not solve the issue, still not precompiling the views in the Web Deploy Package zip file. Running the msbuild manually did not precompile it either.